# Inaccessible base when inner class is class vs struct

Tags: c++

Using g++ 4.4.6, the following does not compile:

```
#include <iostream>

struct Base {};

std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, const Base&) { return os << "Hi\n"; }

template <class T>
class Container
{
   class Derived : Base {};

   template <class U>
   friend std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, const typename Container<U>::Derived&);
};

template <typename U>
std::ostream&
operator<<(std::ostream& os, const typename Container<U>::Derived& der)
{
   return os << static_cast<const Base&>(der);
}

int main()
{
   Container<int>::Derived d;
   std::cout << d;
   return 0;
}
```

Result:

```
/tmp $ g++ test.c
test.c: In function ‘int main()’:
test.c:26: error: ‘Base’ is an inaccessible base of ‘Container<int>::Derived’
/tmp $ g++ --version
```

However, if I simply change

```
class Derived : Base {}
```

to

```
struct Derived : Base {}
```

it compiles without issue.  What's going on here?

Comment: default inheritance is private for class, public for struct

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To make it an answer I'll directly quote the C++ standard, section § 11.2, [class.access.base]

> In the absence of an access-specifier for a base class, public is assumed when the derived class is defined with the class-key struct and private is assumed when the class is defined with the class-key class

So in your case, the first has  private inheritance of `Base`, the second has public.

Comment: I always thought of struct vs. class as having to do with members, never realized it was also for inheritance.  learned something new!